# C dynamic array initialization problem

Tags: c

I'm having a problem initializing an array of structs in my C program. Here's the function where it gets initialized:

```
void InitializeBPStructures() {
    SatCounterTable = (struct SatCounterTableEntry *)malloc(sizeof(struct SatCounterTableEntry) * Counter_Count);
}
```

`Counter_Count` is an integer global variable and `SatCounterTable` is declared earlier in the C source file as

```
static struct SatCounterTableEntry* SatCounterTable;
```

and if it's relevant this is my `SatCounterTable struct`

```
struct SatCounterTableEntry {
    enum SatCounter_State Predict_State;
    md_addr_t tag;
};
```

`md_addr_t` is just a label for an `unsigned int` corresponding to a memory address

The problem is that when I try and compile, I get the following error

```
sim-safe.c:129: error: expected expression before ‘=’ token
```

And the array initialization in my `IntitializeBPStructures()` is on line 129. I'm not sure why this line is a problem. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here's some additional lines of code around the function

```
    struct SatCounterTableEntry
{
    enum SatCounter_State Predict_State;
    md_addr_t tag;
};

/* simulated registers */
static struct regs_t regs;

/* simulated memory */
static struct mem_t *mem = NULL;

/* track number of refs */
static counter_t sim_num_refs = 0;

/* maximum number of inst's to execute */
static unsigned int max_insts;

static struct SatCounterTableEntry* SatCounterTable;

void InitializeBPStructures()
{
    SatCounterTable = (struct SatCounterTableEntry *)malloc(sizeof(struct SatCounterTableEntry) * Counter_Count);
}

void BranchPredict(md_addr_t PC, md_addr_t nextPC, enum Branch_Result result)
{
    if (result == N)
        sim_num_mispred_static++;
    if (result != (myrand() % 2))
        sim_num_mispred_random++;

        sim_num_br++;

}
```

Comment: You also use WAY too many global variables. That stuff is totally deprecated.

Comment: The error might not on line 129. You might miss something somewhere near that line.

Comment: Do you have another type defined called `SatCounterTable`?  It should be recognized by the compiler as an expression since it is a (global) variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon at line 126.

---

Edit: new idea

Do you perhaps have a #define with an extra `=`?

```
#define Counter_Count = 42; /* WRONG */
#define Counter_Count = 42  /* WRONG */
#define Counter_Count 42;   /* WRONG, but it works some time */
#define Counter_Count 42    /* CORRECT */
```

Comment: I can't find anywhere where I'm missing a semicolon, and if I comment out that line, th eprogram compiles fine. If I was missing a semicolon earlier, the compiler would complain wouldn't it?

Comment: That was it, Thanks. Sorry, I really don't program in C often heh

Answer (score 1):

> `SatCounterTable` is declared earlier in the C source file as
>
> ```
> static struct SatCounterTableEntry* SatCounterTable;
> ```

Is that declaration made at file scope or is it within another function?  If the latter, then the `SatCounterTable` name won't be visible inside `InitializeBPStructures()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SatCounterTable = (struct SatCounterTableEntry *)malloc(sizeof(struct SatCounterTableEntry) * Counter_Count);
```

Ugh.  Do me a favor and rewrite that as

```
SatCounterTable = malloc(sizeof *SatCounterTable * Counter_Count);
```

You really don't need to cast the result of `malloc()`; that hasn't been necessary since C89 was adopted.  And using `sizeof` on the object being allocated rather than the type can save you some heartburn (if nothing else, it saves some keystrokes).

The error text suggests that *something* hasn't been defined properly prior to this call; for some reason it isn't recognizing `SatCounterTable`.  I think pmg's on the right track.  You must be missing a semicolon or a curly bracket or something prior to this call.

Answer (score 0):

The C compiler you are using has some reason to believe that SatCounterTable is not an lvalue or primary expression. Given how your variables are named (confusingly I might add), is it possible that you defined a variable at a closer scope also with the name SatCounterTable, such that SatCounterTable is not an assignable expression?

Edit: I would also seriously consider pmg's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned int md_addr_t;
typedef unsigned int counter_t;

int myrand() { return 0; }

struct SatCounterTableEntry
{
    enum SatCounter_State Predict_State;
    md_addr_t tag;
};

static unsigned int Counter_Count;
static unsigned int sim_num_mispred_static;
static unsigned int sim_num_mispred_random;
static unsigned int sim_num_br;
static const unsigned int N = 0;

/* simulated registers */
static struct regs_t {} regs;

/* simulated memory */
static struct mem_t *mem = NULL;

/* track number of refs */
static counter_t sim_num_refs = 0;

/* maximum number of inst's to execute */
static unsigned int max_insts;

static struct SatCounterTableEntry* SatCounterTable;

void InitializeBPStructures()
{
    SatCounterTable = (struct SatCounterTableEntry *)malloc(sizeof(struct SatCounterTableEntry) * Counter_Count);
}

void BranchPredict(md_addr_t PC, md_addr_t nextPC, enum Branch_Result result)
{
    if (result == N)
        sim_num_mispred_static++;
    if (result != (myrand() % 2))
        sim_num_mispred_random++;

        sim_num_br++;

}

int main() {
}
```

You must have errors elsewhere in your code. Have I mentioned how incredibly hideous this design is? You should really be using objects for this.

Comment: I can't. This is for a Computer Arc assignment, and we have to use the SimpleScalar simulator, which is C. This is also the only source file I can change. pmg had the right answer though, I had an = sign in a #define